# Jersey 2.x - Conflicting route priority of PUT and GET

Tags: java, rest, jersey, dropwizard

I'm working with Dropwizard, which uses Jersey internally.  I have two methods on a controller:

`PUT /garbage/[id1,id2,...idN]` is intended to take a path parameter that's a list of numeric IDs representing resources to be updated.  I'm using a regex-based `PathParam` here.  I've fudged the regex in this example because I don't think it matters, but the point is that a single numeric ID should match the regex.

`GET /garbage/[id]` fetches data about a single piece of garbage.

Jersey seems to get confused, despite the difference in method.  When I query with something like

```
curl localhost:8080/garbage/1
```

Jersey gives me a 405 error.  If I take the PUT out of the picture (for example, sabotage the path param regex, or remove it entirely), the GET endpoint works fine.

I assume there is some detail in JAX-RS 3.7.2 I'm missing that explains why this should be the case, but I can't figure out what it is.

Here's the code:

```
@Path("/garbage")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class GarbageController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GarbageController.class);

    @PUT
    @Path("/{params: [\\d,]+}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Timed
    public Response updateGarbage(@PathParam("params") List<PathSegment> params) {
        LOG.warn("updateGarbage");
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{garbageId}")
    public Response getGarbageById(@PathParam("garbageId") long garbageId) {
        LOG.warn("getGarbage");
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of @PathSegment is to handle fragments of the URI which is useful to retrieve Matrix Parameters. For example the method below:

```
@GET
@Path("/book/{id}")
public String getBook(@PathParam("id") PathSegment id) {...}
```

Should be able to handle this request:

```
GET /book;name=EJB 3.0;author=Bill Burke
```

Because the @PathSegment intercepts the entire URL fragment the GET method seems to be ignored. You can handle the comma-separated IDs on the PUT request with a simple String split:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{params}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Timed
public Response updateGarbage(@PathParam("params") String params) {
    LOG.warn("updateGarbage ", params.split(","));
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}
```

You can also change the request format to [query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26571731/7114290) or implement a [Converter/Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32753294/7114290) to handle a custom object. All of them should solve the GET not implemented issue.

<strike>I believe this is not a case of route priorities between GET and PUT but instead this is related to the @Consumes annotation which cannot be used on a GET request. Either DW is ignoring this endpoint or is converting it into the default POST method, which would explain the 405 response for the GET request.</strike>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, \@Consumes is not the issue. I've tried it both with and without the \@Consumes, and it has no effect on the behavior.  (I initially wrote this code without \@Consumes, then added it as a random experiment, then forgot to remove it.  I will go back and remove \@Consumes from the sample code to make this clear.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, although I have not traced far enough into Jersey to know why it works.  The solution is to rewrite the `@GET` method to use the same regex syntax as the `@PUT`.  Jersey will handle the type conversion in the method signature, with the note that it will return a 404 if the type conversion fails (ie, `GET /garbage/xyz`).

```
@PUT
@Path("/{params: .+}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response updateGarbage(@PathParam("params") List<PathSegment> params) {
    LOG.warn("updateGarbage");
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}

@GET
@Path("/{params: .+}")
public Response getGarbageById(@PathParam("params") long garbageId) {
    LOG.warn("getGarbage {}", garbageId);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}
```